# Cannot override block template in magento

Tags: magento, templates, layout, block

I have read quite many posts, but for me nothing is working. Task is quite simpe - I need to override core template review/product/view/list.phtml with my own, let's say my_list.phtml

My configuration is as follows. Layout.xml (head modification is  working)

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<review_product_list>
    <reference name="head">
    ..
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="myreview.product_additional_data"
               as="myreview_product_additional_data" template="review/product/view/my_list.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

Config.xml

```
 <frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <myreview>
                <file>myreview/layout.xml</file>
            </myreview>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

I can change core file review.xml and it works as expected, this line

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
```

but this is not I am expecting.

If I change 
reference name="product.info"
to
reference name="content" My template shows up, but not in place. If I try to debug, blocks are rendered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<review_product_list>
    <reference name="product.info.product_additional_data">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <tpl>review/product/view/my_list.phtml</tpl>
        </action>
    </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

or

```
<review_product_list>
    <action method="setTemplate" block="product.info.product_additional_data">
        <tpl>review/product/view/my_list.phtml</tpl>
    </action>
</review_product_list>
```

Comment: tpl short for template? and can we change the block type as well?